# Enable CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS without reboot/recompile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server that I am troubleshooting, and I would like to use iotop. However, it seems that 12.04 doesn't have CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS enabled by default (required by iotop).

I really want to avoid rebooting the machine. Is there any way to get it enabled without doing so?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [KSplice](http://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/download-ubuntu) to do what you want here. At least assuming that a kernel for Ubuntu 12.04 exists with that configuration option enabled.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of this. I think it might work. Thanks!